# Ubuntu 12.04 - Bluetooth Phone

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 12.04 lts. When I want to connect my phone via bluetooth, it doesn't be recognized. I works fine on Windows 7. 
On the other hand, in the phone, I see my laptop but i cant connect with it.

Anybody has an idea on how to solve this?

icon is showing that bluetooth is on but it hasn't option of adding a device..

Comment: What is the model of the phone?  What do you see in System Settings > Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2):

first you need enabled on your phone the "discover" mode, then in your Ubuntu Desktop click on your bluetooth icon and select "setup a new device..." this open a windows witch will guide you to pair you system with your phone.